Visual Studio 2022 & Git - Adding and existing project to the repository that is in use
I have a simple ASP.NET Web API project in my solution. The project was already pushed to the repository.
I added another project to this solution in VS 2022 (for example a unit test project), but my question is how do I push it into the same repository so that both projects are on the same remote repository?
Thank you!
I tried everything that I could think of.

What do you mean by "push it into the same repo"? Please may you share some clarification there. Maybe add a folder structure for what you expect and what you current have?

The project names are just for testing. So the "Testing.EF.API" project is already added to soruce control.  But my question is how can i add the "EF.Test" to the same repository so than when a clone the repository, I get both projects on my local machine. I uploaded an image here: https://ibb.co/ZWHrcDN

You might be talking either of git mono-repo, or sub-modules.
